# Always pass paremeter to apache reverse proxy

Tags: mod-rewrite, proxy, apache2, reverse-proxy

I got a server running on http. With reverse proxy I was able to wrap it into https and server it as https.
The http server runs on port `9000` and expects the `GET` parameter `action`.

So with this config, I can wrap my http in https:

```
SSLEngine On
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem

SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPass /snapshot/ http://localhost:9000/
ProxyPassReverse /snapshot/ http://localhost:9000/
```

However I still want to redirect from /snapshot/ to a query parameter **after** a slash:

**https://** example.com/snapshot/ -> **https://** example.com:9000/?action=snapshot

I can't get my head around this redirection. I tried some RewriteRule but only could get it to get redirected to /snapshot?action=snapshot.
Please be aware that the parameter should be **after** the slash and that the URL shouldn't display the action parameter.

How do I manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the RewriteRule instead of the ReverseProxy did the trick. Replacing the SSLProxyEngine On lines with these lines works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule snapshot/ http://localhost:9000/?action=snapshot [P]
RewriteRule stream/ http://localhost:9000/?action=stream [P]
```